# Pressing the mouse down can follow the mouse movement, but lifting it up does not remove the movement event

Tags: vue.js, svg

It is expected that it can press the mouse button to follow the mouse movement, and release the mouse button to stop following the movement, achieving an effect of dragging the mouse to move.

```js
createBom() {
  let bom = null;
  this.data.forEach((item) => {
    bom = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
    bom.setAttributeNS(
      "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",
      "xlink:href",
      `#${item.id}`
    );
    bom.setAttribute("width", item.width);
    bom.setAttribute("height", item.height);
    bom.setAttribute("x", item.x);
    bom.setAttribute("y", item.y);
    bom.setAttribute("cursor", "move");
    bom.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
      console.log("鼠标抬起");
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
        this.move(e, bom, item);
      });
    });
    bom.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
      console.log("鼠标按下");
      document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
        this.move(e, bom, item);
      });
    });

    this.parent.appendChild(bom);
  });
}
createBom()
```

Comment: What’s the question? What’s wrong with the code?

Comment: The example in the docs only show passing a named function to `removeEventListener`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you want to remove an event listener you need to pass the same handle function as you add it. Create a new function won't do anything. Example:

```js
// Add the event listener
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// Remove the event listener
button.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

Second, if you want your svg tags to be draggable, you should use the [drag and drop api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API), which doesn't need to remove event listener at all.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something like:

```js
function addListener(scope,name,func){
  scope.addEventListener(name, func);
  return () => scope.removeEventListener(name,func);
}
```

usage:

```js
let clickRemove = addListener( document, "click" , () => console.log("Hello World!") );

later:

clickRemove();
```